# Invalid UI Component element name: Export button not working?

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, magento-2.1.7, export

I have created grid using ui component.

```
  <container name="page_listing_top">
    <exportButton name="export_button">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">sales_report_report_listing.sales_report_report_listing_columns.ids</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </exportButton>
</container>
```

Comment: While exporting report ? and which version of magento2 ?

Comment: @KeyurShah - magento 2.1.7

Comment: Could you please add your step when you are facing this error? @jassi

Comment: @KeyurShah Thank u. I got solution by adding below posted answer after dataSource element.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
    <exportButton name="export_button"/>
</listingToolbar>
```